# What are $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

Let $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ ($\ell$ is an integer). Could we describe the elements in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ explicitly? Here $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ is the $p$-adic field at $\ell$. Thank you very much.

Comment: $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is the set of algebraic numbers: complex numbers that are solutions to polynomials with rational coefficients. That's about as explicit as I can give. Would a similar explanation of $\overline{\Bbb Q}_\ell$ suffice?

Comment: @Mike, thank you very much. Is $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ strictly contained in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, since $\Bbb Q \subset \Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed. (Of course, the algebraic closure is an entirely algebraic object, but the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$ (abstractly) is isomorphic to the field of algebraic numbers (a subset of $\Bbb C$). This is probably not an issue that matters to you.)

Comment: @Mike, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are indeed isomorphic as *abstract fields*, i.e., both are algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero and with transcendence degree $2^{ℵ_0}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Of course, this isomorphism does not preserve topology: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ is not complete, for example, but $\mathbb{C}$ is.
The completion of of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ is $\mathbb{C}_{\ell}$. There are many desriptions about the algebraic closures, but it depends on what you want to know. Perhaps you find also the following question interesting in this context: [How far are the $p$-adic numbers from being algebraically closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16724/how-far-are-the-p-adic-numbers-from-being-algebraically-closed).