# Uniqueness of residue field of a complete field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

> Suppose that we have a field $F$ which is complete under an absolute value $|\cdot|_1$, and its residue field is $k$. My question is, can we come up with some other non-trivial absolute value $|\cdot|_2$ on $F$, such that $F$ remains complete under it, but instead produces a residue field $k_2$ that is not isomorphic to $k$.
>
> Now, clearly this is not possible if we drop the assumption of $F$ being complete, because on $\mathbb Q$ we have the $p-$adic and the $q-$adic absolute values which produce different residue fields.

The reason I am asking such a question, is because I notice a tendency in literature to refer to complete discretely valued fields without referring to the absolute values, which are also part of the datum. I was wondering if there was a reason for doing that, besides, say that the choice of absolute value would be not be relevant for the statements they are trying to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completion $\mathbb{C}_p$  of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ with respect to its usual absolute value has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{C}$.  Moreover, these fields are both algebraically closed and of characteristic zero.  These three pieces of information tell us that they are isomorphic as fields.  This means that all the complete fields $\mathbb{C}_p : p$ prime are isomorphic, but they have nonisomorphic residue fields, since the residue field of $\mathbb{C}_p$ is $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$.

Edit: Here is a sketch of the main results of transcendence degrees.  Let $k \subseteq L$ be a field.  A subset $S \subseteq L$ is *algebraically independent over $k$* if for any finite subset $\{s_1, ... , s_n\} \subseteq S$, the condition $f \in k[X_1, ... , X_n]$, $f(s_1, ... , s_n) = 0$ implies $f = 0$.

A *transcendence basis* of $L/k$ is a maximal algebraically independent set.  Transcendence bases exist, and any two transcendence bases have the same cardinality.  If $S$ is a transcendence basis, then up to isomorphism the field $k(S)$ depends only on the cardinality of $S$, because $k(S)$ is isomorphic to quotient field of the polynomial ring over $k$ in $|S|$ indeterminates.  The extension $L/k(S)$ is algebraic.

Let $L, K$ be two algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero.  They each contain a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Suppose $S, T$ are transcendence bases of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ with the same cardinality.  Then $L$ and $K$ are isomorphic: there is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(S) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(T)$.  Since $L$ is algebraically closed, and algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(S)$, it is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$.  The same for $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}(T)$.  Any two algebraic closures of a given field are noncanonically isomorphic, so the isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(S) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(T)$ extends to an isomorphism $L \rightarrow K$.

Suppose moreover that $L$ is an *uncountable* algebraically closed field.  In that case, $L$ is classified up to isomorphism by its cardinality and its characteristic.  This is because if $S$ is a transcendence basis of $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the cardinality of $L$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$, which is equal to the cardinality of $S$.

Thus any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and cardinality that of $\mathbb{R}$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It's a general result from field theory about transcendence degrees.

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ contains some [non-algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221160/the-extension-mathbbq-3-mathbbq-is-not-algebraic) elements (over $\mathbb{Q}$) so it can't be isomorphic as a field to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Did you mean complete algebraically closed characteristic zero fields ?

Comment: What does $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ have to do with anything?

Comment: See my edit.  Sorry I realize my answer was misleading, in addition to algebraically closed and characteristic zero, you also need them to have the same the same transcendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes it is clear now, except what would be $S$ exactly (axiom of choice ?..) in the case of $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}_p$

Comment: I don't know.  Axiom of choice just tells you that it exists.  You're not going to be able to write down an isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: I guess the problem is quite the same as finding the isomorphisms between $\mathbb{C}$ and itself. For this I'd say we start by looking at $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\pi)}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(e)}$ and we obtain an automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\pi,e)}$ switching $\pi$ and $e$. Finally we write $\mathbb{C}$ as an extension of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\pi,e)}$, and we repeat the same with many more transcendental elements, using the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You'd have to do that with uncountably many elements, it's pretty much impossible.  In any case, isomorphisms $\mathbb{C}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{C}_q$ for $q \neq p$ exist, so you can transfer over the absolute value on $\mathbb{C}_q$  to one on $\mathbb{C}_p$ and get a different residue field which is not isomorphic to the usual one of $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: It's also an unsolved problem whether there exists a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which contains both $\pi$ and $e$.

Answer (score 3):

Information that may be helpful:

In such fields $F$, describing $|\cdot|$ is the same as describing the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of the ring of $|\cdot|$-local integers. I usually think of this ideal as being the things whose powers converge to $0$, but if there’s an equivalent definition of this ideal that depends only an algebraic properties of elements, the topology will be unique.

For disconnected local fields, i.e. for $\Bbb Q_p$ and its finite extensions and for the fields $\kappa((t))$ for which $\kappa$ is finite, there is a purely algebraic definition of the maximal ideal, so there is no other non-trivial absolute value.

I suppose an equivalent characterization of fields with only the one absolute value would be that every field automorphism is necessarily continuous.

Comment: What would be the algebraic definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (why is there only one possible "ring of integers" in $\mathbb{Q}_p$) ? For a number field $K$ it is obvious because there is only one embedding on $\mathbb{Z}$ into $K$, and $\mathcal{O}_K$ are the integral (over $\mathbb{Z}$) elements of $K$. But it doesn't work for $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (which is not contained in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$)

Comment: I was hoping nobody would ask, @user1952009. There are other characterizations of the maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z_p$, but the one I use is something like this: $\alpha\in\Bbb Q_p$ is in $p\Bbb Z_p$ if and only if for every natural number $m$ prime to $p$, $1-\alpha$ has an $m$-th root in the field. (In this formulation, you need to know $p$ beforehand.)

Comment: It seems [this](http://urlz.fr/5ize) might help for showing what you said, using the $p$-adic binomial series of $(1+p a)^{1/m}, a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Right you are, @user1952009. Or, the fact that $(1+t)^{1/m}$ has no $p$’s in the denominators. Or, an application of Hensel’s Lemma. There’s also a way of applying the series for $\log(1+t)$.